# Add Key and Values from NSDictionary to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` with keys **UserID** and **UserName**.

I also have an `NSDictionary` with keys **UserID** and **UserScore**.

How do I add the key and values for **UserScore** from the `NSDictionary` to the `NSMutableArray` so that the **UserName** and **UserScore** represent the same **UserID**?

NSMutableArray:

```
UserID = 123,
UserName = JohnP
```

NSDictionary:

```
UserID = 123,
UserScore = 100
```

Desired output as NSMutableArray:

```
UserID = 123,
UserName = JohnP,
UserScore = 100
```

Below is how I retrieve data into the `NSMutableArray` using `Parse` and then grab data to a label:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          FacebookFriends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                      }];

NSString *friendname = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[FacebookFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];
```

Comment: Your `NSMutableArray` structure is not clear. What do u mean?

Comment: Write, pls, how u add values to the array.

Comment: NSArray does not store key-value pairs. How u store your data in array? Write code example, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you really just wanna use an NSMutableDictionary which is made to store value-key pairs.

You can give your mutable dictionary values from your other dictionary simply by pointing to its key-value (objectForKey).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want to combine two dictionaries into one:

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = ...;
NSDictionary *dict2 = ...;
NSMutableDictionary *combined = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSNumber *userid = dict1[@"UserID"];
NSAssert(userid, @"UserID missing from dict1");
NSAssert([userid isEqualToString:dict2[@"UserID"]], @"Mismatched UserIDs");
NSString *username = dict1[@"UserName"];
NSAssert(username, @"Username missing from dict1");
NSNumber *score = dict2[@"UserScore"];
NSAssert(score, @"Score missing from dict2");
combined[@"UserID"] = userid;
combined[@"UserName"] = username;
combined[@"UserScore"] = score;
```

However I also suspect you have an array of dictionaries.  If so, let me know.

Comment: The issue I am having is that I can't do this with a dictionary - `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row`. If I could find a way to select the values from the dictionary like that, I would not need to combine the two.

Comment: @MichaelDeluca So you do have an array of dictionaries?